# finding button inside <InsertItemTemplate> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to create a small jQuery script that blackens out the background of a page, brings up a small form, and then takes the form away and restores the background when the form is submitted / cancelled.

I have successfully demo;d this with a [JSFDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnHalsey/uU4ha/7/) but I have written that in plain HTML, and in reality I need to do this in an ASP.NET ASPX page.

The small form I need to pop up is inside a fieldset, inside an InsertItemTemplate.  I can get the backgound to blacken out, the form pops up, but when I press either the Insert or Cancel Buttons, I can't get the background (div with id="backing") to go away.  My jQuery can't find the buttons even though I'm targeting them by id.

Here is the jQuery in my ASPX page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var btnCancel = document.getElementById('btnInsertCancel');
        var btnAddContact = document.getElementById('btnAddContact');

        // when add contact button is pressed
        $(btnAddContact).click(function () {
            $('#backing').fadeIn();
        });

        // when submit button in add customer pop up is pressed
        $(btnCancel).click(function () {
            $('#backing').fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

The Insert Item template looks like this

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <fieldset id="newContact">
        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="height: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%;">
                    Title:
                </td>
                <td style="width: 80%; padding-left: 5px;">
                    <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="drpITitle" runat="server"
                        DataSourceID="objTitle" DataTextField="TITLEDESC" 
                        DataValueField="TITLEID" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("TITLEID") %>' >
                    </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTitle" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Title (Required)"
                    ValidationGroup="valClientContactI" InitialValue="" ControlToValidate="drpITitle"
                    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Firstname:
                </td>
                <td style="width: 80%; padding-left: 5px;">
                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtIFirstname" Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CONTACTFNAME")%>'>
                </telerik:RadTextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstname" runat="server" ErrorMessage="First name (Required)"
                    ValidationGroup="valClientContactI" InitialValue="" ControlToValidate="txtIFirstname"
                    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Surname:
                </td>
                <td style="width: 80%; padding-left: 5px;">
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtISurname" Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CONTACTSNAME")%>'>
                    </telerik:RadTextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSurname" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Surname (Required)"
                    ValidationGroup="valClientContactI" InitialValue="" ControlToValidate="txtISurname"
                    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    DOB:
                </td>
                <td style="width: 80%; padding-left: 5px;">
                    <telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="dtpIDOB" SelectedDate='<%# Bind("DOB")%>'>
                    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Position:
                </td>
                <td style="width: 80%; padding-left: 5px;">
                    <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="drpIPosition" runat="server"
                        DataSourceID="objPosition" DataTextField="POSITIONDESC" 
                        DataValueField="POSITIONID" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("CONTACTPOSITIONID") %>'>
                    </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPosition" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Position (Required)"
                    ValidationGroup="valClientContactI" InitialValue="" ControlToValidate="drpIPosition"
                    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Marketing:
                </td>
                <td style="width: 80%; padding-left: 5px;">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIMarketing" runat="server" 
                        Enabled="true" Checked='<%# Bind("MARKETING") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="server" CommandName="PerformInsert" Text="Insert" ValidationGroup="valClientContactI" ClientIDMode="Static">
                    </asp:Button>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnInsertCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
                    </asp:Button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </fieldset>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
```

Any suggestions about how I can target either the Inseert Button, or Cancel button would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: If you are going to use jQuery at all, please throw away code like `getElementById` and use jQuery selectors. Have updated answer to take this into account.

Comment: Q: Where is `btnAddContact` button defined? I used the existing insert/cancel buttons in my example as I could not find this control.

Comment: I have a user control storing all the html / controls, and the that button is right at the top of the page.  The page is doing a lot of other things as well which I figured you didn't need to see.

Comment: That's OK. You obviously got the idea now anyway about delegated events. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you can use ID's

*ID's are fine for unique controls (if anything, preferable, as there should not be duplicates and the jQuery look-up is faster).* In this specific case you will never have more than one `InsertItem` template visible at once so your ID's will be fine. If that is ever not the class, use classes instead as `Anoop Joshi` suggests*.

*note: The other reason you might want to switch to classes, and class selectors, is that Telerik controls (which you use) do not properly support `ClientIDMode`  http://www.telerik.com/forums/clientidmode-support-for-asp-net-4-0

The only other thing that can happen is when elements are added to the DOM dynamically. If that turns out to be the case, switch to using `delegated` events like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#btnInsertCancel', function () {
        $('#backing').fadeIn();
    });

    // when submit button in add customer pop up is pressed
    $(document).on('click' , '#btnAddContact', function () {
        $('#backing').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

These listen at an ancestor, *then* apply the selector, *then* apply the function to any matching elements that generated the event.

The preference is to use the first non-changing ancestor in your DOM. Failing that (you do not show the rest of the page) you can use `document` which receives all bubbled events on the page.

Note: `$(function(){YOUR CODE});` is the preferred short version of `$(document).ready(function () {YOUR CODE});`

### "Class" based version

Assuming you have to use classes instead (for any of the reason mentioned) the code becomes:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.btnInsertCancel', function () {
        $('#backing').fadeIn();
    });

    // when submit button in add customer pop up is pressed
    $(document).on('click' , '.btnAddContact', function () {
        $('#backing').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

### ASPX:

```
<td colspan="2">
    <asp:Button class="btnInsert" runat="server" CommandName="PerformInsert" Text="Insert" ValidationGroup="valClientContactI" ClientIDMode="Static">
    </asp:Button>
    <asp:Button class="btnInsertCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
    </asp:Button>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @TrueBlueAussie.  I did already have ClientIDMode="Static" on the buttons, but tried the new syntax you suggested with the class name and it works.  Thank you

Comment: @John Halsey: That's what happens when I don't scroll far enough to the right :) I will remove the irrelevant part of my answer as it is now just a simple `delegated` event question (which occur a lot on SO). :)